# creating a list of tuples using for loop

Tags: python, list

I want to create a list of tuples from a list and position of each element in list. Here is what I am trying.

```
def func_ (lis):
    ind=0
    list=[]
    for h in lis:
       print h
       return h
```

Let's say argument of function:

```
lis=[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I was wondering how to make use if ind.

Desired output:

```
[(1,0),(2,1),(3,2),(4,3),(5,4)]
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it reads correctly (highlight the code, then click the button that looks like `{}`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this a lot easier with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> lis=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> [(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(lis)]
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
>>>
```

---

You might also consider using `xrange`, `len`, and `zip` as @PadraicCunningham proposed:

```
>>> lis=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> zip(lis, xrange(len(lis))) # Call list() on this in Python 3
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
>>>
```

Documentation for all of these functions can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

---

If you must define your own function, then you can do something like:

```
def func_(lis):
    ind = 0
    lst = [] # Don't use 'list' as a name; it overshadows the built-in
    for h in lis:
        lst.append((h, ind))
        ind += 1 # Increment the index counter
    return lst
```

Demo:

```
>>> def func_(lis):
...     ind = 0
...     lst = []
...     for h in lis:
...         lst.append((h, ind))
...         ind += 1
...     return lst
...
>>> lis=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> func_(lis)
[(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4)]
>>>
```

Comment: More concise: `zip(lis, itertools.count())`

Comment: @augurar, no need for itertools  `zip(lis, xrange(len(lis)))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Nice one!  I'll incorporate it into my answer. :)

Comment: @iCodez, I tried those  methods.  I want use of function.

Comment: @Phil2014 - Well, see my edit then.  Note however that the first two solutions I gave will be more efficient.